# How to post array from javascript to php?

Tags: php, jquery

I want to post an array using Jquery Ajax to php. Is this possible ?

Thanks

**EDIT:**

I tried following :

```
type: "POST",
url: "path",
data: "styles=" + strstyles + "&templateId=" + custTempId, //strstyles is an associative array
dataType: "json",
success: function (data) { .....}
```

but, styles hold no data. I  spent a lot of time, before adding data type to the declaration. What can be the reason for "styles" being posted as null ?

**Second Edit**

I want to post style sheet dom object and save the class names and properties to DB. With the above edit, adding datatype did not help. I think it is b'coz the string is not in json format as follows -

```
    {"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}
```

As the my string has double quotes, it is not following the format, and I think that's the reason, I'm getting an empty array. How can I handle this ?

Comment: hi buddy, use JSON.stringify to create json strings from objects, see my solution in few minutes

Answer (score 2):

With jQuery it is very easy:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: location.href,
    data: data,//data is array
    dataType: "json",
    success : function () {
        // Something after success
    }
});
```

Comment: @ Alexander.Plutov, Hey Thanks :) - to use json, do I need any library files ?

Comment: @KutePHP No, [JSON](http://www.json.org/) makes use of the native JavaScript object literal. You can decode with JavaScript's `eval()`, however, it raises security concerns if the JSON isn't trusted. See the JSON site for a parser.

Answer (score 0):

You can use in following way too

```
$.ajax({

type: "POST",
url: location.href,
data: ({'data[]' : array}),//array is array
dataType: "json",
success : function () {
    // Something after success
}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to use JSON, PHP can automatically create [arrays from Html forms](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays)
so you could do something like this:

```
type: "POST",
url: "path",
data: "styles[key1]=" + strstyles.val1 + "&styles[key2]=" + strstyles.val2 + ... + "&templateId=" + custTempId
...
```

that is if you want to have an associative array in php, but if you want just an array you could do

```
data: "styles[]=" + strstyles.val1 + "&templateId=" + custTempId
```

Answer (score 0):

In POST call you dont use & , So your code should be 
something like

```
type: "POST",
url: "path",
data: {styles: strstyles , templateId: custTempId}, //strstyles is an associative array
dataType: "json",
success: function (data) { .....}
```

is that point clear? 
So coming to my solution,

1. you should download JSON parser from http://www.mediafire.com/?x6k3su7bbdrcta8.
2. Create object strstylesOBJ, code: `var strstylesOBJ = {};`
3. insert your `strstyles` array into `strstylesOBJ` and stringify it then pass to it in your post call

   ```
    strstylesOBJ.styles = strstyles;    
    strstyles = JSON.stringify(strstylesOBJ);
   ```
4. In PHP code you refecth your array using `$strstyles = json_decode($_POST['styles']);`
5. do `var_dump($strstyles)` and please tell what was the output.

regards

Ayaz Alavi